# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')

Tags: react-native

Eu estou tentando iniciar um projeto com **React Native**. Mas quando tento utilizar o **react-navigation** esse erro aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**App.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Copiei o mesmo código da página [Hello React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html)

Instalei o **react-navigation** com o seguinte comando:

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Porem o erro persiste em insistir.

Answer (score 8):

Isso acontece por conta de um problema com a versão 3.0. Eu recomendo a utilização da versão 2.18.2

Passos para o `downgrade`:

```
> npm uninstall react-navigation

> npm install react-navigation@2.18.2 --save
```

Iniciar pacote:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Rodar o app:

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: It worked correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Resolveu pra mim também! Valeu!!

Comment: Deu certo aqui também!

Comment: Você é o cara. Para quem tá entrando nesse mundo do react/react-native falta muita informação :(

Answer (score 3):

Estava enfrentando esse problema também, e [conforme a documentação](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) na versão 3 do react-navigation é necessário alterar o arquivo `MainActivity.java` para executar ele no Android. Consegui fazer funcionar com esses passos:

1) Instalar os pacotes necessários

```
npm install --save react-navigator
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
```

2) Editar o arquivo `android/app/src/main/java/com/mobile/MainActivity.java`, deixando-o assim:

```java
package com.mobile;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
/** Adicionar esses imports **/
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
    * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
    * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
    */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "mobile";
    }

    /** Adicionar esse método **/
    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
      return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
        @Override
        protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
        return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
        }
      };
    }
}
```

3) Rodar o aplicativo novamente com os comandos:

```
react-native link
react-native start --reset-cache
react-native run-android
```

O comando `run-android` é importante nesse caso para compilar novamente o apk do aplicativo Android, eu tive problemas pois estava tentando resolver só pelo live reload e `start --reset-cache`, porém faltou esse detalhe.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!